# Changing background color doesn't work well

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the background color of my webpage using a hamburger menu. There are 4 color options on my hamburger menu. I managed to get a change on the background when clicking on the color of my choice. But that change only happens once. When I clicked another color and come back to click that same color from earlier on, it doesn't respond. The color seems to change only once, and not more than that.

The repository to my GitHub code is here: https://github.com/tand100b/Winc_Academy

```js
const changeColorButton1 = document.getElementById("color1");
changeColorButton1.addEventListener("click", function() {
  changeClassRedBackground();
});

const changeColorButton2 = document.getElementById("color2");
changeColorButton2.addEventListener("click", function() {
  changeClassOrangeBackground();
});

const changeColorButton3 = document.getElementById("color3");
changeColorButton3.addEventListener("click", function() {
  changeClassPurpleBackground();
});

const changeColorButton4 = document.getElementById("color4");
changeColorButton4.addEventListener("click", function() {
  changeClassGreenBackground();
});

const changeClassRedBackground = function() {
  const bodyElement = document.body;
  bodyElement.classList.add("red-background");
}

const changeClassOrangeBackground = function() {
  const bodyElement = document.body;
  bodyElement.classList.add("orange-background");
};

const changeClassPurpleBackground = function() {
  const bodyElement = document.body;
  bodyElement.classList.add("purple-background");
};

const changeClassGreenBackground = function() {
  const bodyElement = document.body;
  bodyElement.classList.add("green-background");
};
```

```css
body {
  background-color: pink;
}

.red-background {
  background-color: red;
}

.orange-background {
  background-color: orange;
}

.purple-background {
  background-color: purple;
}

.green-background {
  background-color: green;
}

.btn-toggle-nav {
  width: 60px;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: #f98f39;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/tniUv.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 60%;
  background-position: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-toggle-nav:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.navbar ul {
  padding-top: 15px;
  /*  visibility: hidden; */
}

.navbar ul li {
  line-height: 60px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: white;
  width: 300px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  display: block;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  height: calc(100vh-60px);
  z-index: 1000;
}

.list {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<div class="btn-toggle-nav"></div>
<aside class="navbar">
  <ul class="list">
    <li><a id="color1" href="#">Red</a></li>
    <li><a id="color2" href="#">Orange</a></li>
    <li><a id="color3" href="#">Purple</a></li>
    <li><a id="color4" href="#">Green</a></li>
  </ul>
</aside>
```

Can someone please look at my code and suggest what I can do?

Comment: Hi, please post the code here, just in case the GitHub page gets removed and we end up with an empty question.

Comment: Right-click on the page, select "Inspect", and select the body and look at it's class to see why.

Comment: Side-note: Try changing the `btn-toggle-nav` class height to `60px` (to match the height), because `20%` renders as `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I suggest declaring variable bodyElement only once at the top of the file because each time it would be the same body element:

```
const bodyElement = document.body
```

Next, we create function that will check if body has any style classes in its classList. If it's not empty (length more than one) we remove all classes, and do nothing otherwise:

```
const isBodyHasStyle = () => bodyElement.classList.length ? bodyElement.classList = '' : null
```

Then, on each button click we going to call our new function:

```
changeColorButton1.addEventListener("click", function() {
    isBodyHasStyle()
    changeClassRedBackground();
});
```

Do the same with other buttons.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to accomplish this is by setting a data attribute on the background, based on the selected color. Just add a color data value to each of the menu items and set the body background to that color.

```js
const toggleMenu = (event) => {
  event.target.closest('.navbar').classList.toggle('open');
};

const changeColor = (event) => {
  document.body.dataset.background = event.target.dataset.color;
  toggleMenu(event); /* do not call ~ to stay open */
};

document.querySelector('.btn-toggle-nav')
  .addEventListener('click', toggleMenu)

document.querySelectorAll('.color-picker')
  .forEach(e => e.addEventListener('click', changeColor));
```

```css
/* CSS reset */
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body { display: flex; background-color: #222; }
ul { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; }

body[data-background="red"]      { background-color: red    }
body[data-background="orange"]   { background-color: orange }
body[data-background="purple"]   { background-color: purple }
body[data-background="green"]    { background-color: green  }
body[data-background="default"]  { /* Do not set the background-color */ }

a[data-color="red"]     { color: red; }
a[data-color="orange"]  { color: orange; }
a[data-color="purple"]  { color: purple; }
a[data-color="green"]   { color: green; }
a[data-color="default"] { color: #222; }

.list {
  position: absolute;
  display: none; /* hide menu (default) */
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  width: 6em;
  left: 2em;
  background: #444;
}

.list li a { text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; }
.list li a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }

.navbar {
  position: relative;
  width: 2em;
  background-color: #444;
}

.navbar.open .list {
  display: flex; /* show menu */
}

.btn-toggle-nav {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/tniUv.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 60%;
  background-position: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<aside class="navbar">
  <div class="btn-toggle-nav"></div>
  <ul class="list">
    <li><a class="color-picker" href="#" data-color="red">Red</a></li>
    <li><a class="color-picker" href="#" data-color="orange">Orange</a></li>
    <li><a class="color-picker" href="#" data-color="purple">Purple</a></li>
    <li><a class="color-picker" href="#" data-color="green">Green</a></li>
    <li><a class="color-picker" href="#" data-color="default">Default</a></li>
  </ul>
</aside>
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I code in Javascript to automatically close the hamburger menu once a color has been picked and the background color has changed?

Comment: @dmarmoset I updated the snippet to toggle the menu open/closed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you don't have multiple classes conflicting with each other, also try to [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) your code, here is an alternative I came up with:

```
    const changeColor = (e) => {
      const bodyElement = document.querySelector('body');
      const colorIdMap = {
        "color1": "red-background",
        "color2": "orange-background",
        "color3": "purple-background",
        "color4": "green-background"
      }
      bodyElement.className = colorIdMap[e.target.id];
    }
    
    const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.list li');
    btns.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', changeColor))
```